# install4j: how to disable the option for a second install on an update

Tags: install4j

I created my first installer with install4j. Now I tried an update of my application, and it works, but I am asked if I want to make an update or an additional installation.

I only want the option for update. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Christian.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "Alert for update installation" property on the "Welcome" screen of your installer and use

context.isUpdateInstallation()

in condition expressions to hide certain screens (for example the "Installation location" screen)